# Is it possible to exceed the limit of 20 hosted service in windows azure bizspark membership?

Tags: azure

We are coming up with a SAAS application on windows azure platform.
Initially it will be one hosted service per tenant.
But I realized that there is a limit of 20 hosted services in my Bizspark membership.
Per my resarch, this has to be requested to Micrsoft offline.

My question here is:
1.How to aquire additional hosted service programatically?
2. What is the cost per service?

Comment: I'd be very worried about that model - the single service per tenant will go down regularly on patch tuesday etc.

Comment: it is named "single service per tenant", not "single instance per tenant". I don't see what your concerns are. It would be hell from management prespective.

Answer (score 4):

You can't "acqire" addition hosted services programatically. Your account will always have a limit.
In order to adjust that limit you must contact the [Windows Azure Support](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/contact/) and open a ticket for increasing Hosted Services quota. You might be required to go through a credid check process for this.
There is no such thing as "cost-per-service" in Windows Azure. There is "cost-per-what-you-use". You may want to overview the [Windows Azure Pricing page](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/).

Let me put the things like that (For pricing):

You will pay the same ammount of money for either of the following:

- 20 Cloud services, each with 1 production role with SMALL VM Size

**OR**

- 1 CLoud Service with 20 production roles with SMALL VM size

But, in a single Cloud Service you only have a limit of 25 roles, and no port sharing (i.e. port 80 will only be available to a single role).

I suggest that you take a look at the [Windows Azure Marketplace for Applications lab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_introtowazmarketplace.aspx), where Microsoft's team is giving some guidelines in how to build multi-tenant app.

You may also check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445799/windows-azure-multi-tenancy) and [that article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh689716.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There is also another alternative. I you have an Enterprise Agreement, which you should do to getter prices, you can create as much as subscriptions as you want.
For each subscription you can setup 20 hosted services.